# Attribute format to element in XAML serialization

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, serialization

When I serialize this POCO using XamlServices.Save():

```
public class GtdConfig
{
    public string LocalDbInstanceName { get; set; }
}
```

The .xaml file will be:

```
<GtdConfig LocalDbInstanceName="v12.0">
</GtdConfig>
```

How can I get the file like this:

```
<GtdConfig>
    <GtdConfig.LocalDbInstanceName>v12.0</GtdConfig.LocalDbInstanceName>
</GtdConfig>
```

For XML serailziation, there are XmlElementAttribute and XmlAttributeAttribute to do this. But I cannot find these attributes in XAML serialization.

Comment: Why? They should be each others equivalent.

Comment: When I have too many attributes, the .xaml file cannot read easily. If I can use the nest elements, the indents make it clearer.
For XML, there are XmlElementAttribute and XmlAttributeAttribute to do this. But I cannot find these attributes in XAML serialization.